# Textarea: Allow to begin with linebreak

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic/Cordova App. There is a `textarea` visible where user can input some data, which is transferred to the server.

Here, the user should be able to input line breaks. The problem I'm facing right now is that it's only possible after they input the first character; and it's not possible to begin with a line break. The `ng-model` cuts off the beginning line breaks. How can I achieve my goal?

The `textarea` looks like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="card.text" id="text-message" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the use case? It seems odd to have white space at the beginning of text.

Comment: Can you set an invisible white-space character (`&#x200b`) as the first character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2010 you can apply `ng-trim="false"` to your element to stop this behaviour like so:

```
<textarea ng-model="card.text" ng-trim="false" id="text-message" rows="20"></textarea>
```